# Angular Cli: How to serve 2 apps?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need 2 different apps on same project:

- index.html > mainApp Module
- login.html > loginApp Module

(this is required for security reasons managed by Spring Security)

I vave angular-cli.json described below:

```
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "login.html",
      "main": "login.ts",
      "test": "login-test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "login-tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "login-app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "login-styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```

But only deploy the first one (on "apps" array).

If I invert Login at position [0], this works, but mainApp Module doesn't.

Apparently the reason is, Angular Cli doesn't inject created JS files on the second html.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **UPDATE**: Multiple apps are supported now by the CLI - docs are [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps)

Currently the Angular CLI does not support multiple apps. It is something that will be supported in the future.

For now you could work under separate directories (aka separate CLI projects).

Comment: You're welcome. If you do move away from the CLI just be aware that you will need to create your own build process for both projects from the ground up (outside the CLI).

Comment: The `--app` option is now available in `ng build` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your .angular-cli.json file and setup multiple apps

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../Application.Web.UI/wwwroot/app/Candidate",
      "assets": [
        "assets"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.candidate.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app_andidate",
      "styles": [ "share/css/material.scss" ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../Application.Web.UI/wwwroot/app/Company",
      "assets": [
        "assets"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.company.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app_company",
      "styles": [ "share/css/material.scss" ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Can you specify what ports to run each app on?

Comment: Not in the config. But you can run your app on next available port if 4200 is already in use  ```ng serve --app 1 --port=0```